# Extracting text from HTML file using Python (Music Artist / Title)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract from a page the artist and song title.

The page:
http://www.swr3.de//-/id=47424/cf=42/did=65794/93avs/index.html?hour=5&date=2015-10-23

```
                 <div class="detail-body">
                   <h4 class="detail-heading" itemprop="name">No son of mine</h4>
                   <span itemprop="byArtist" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup"><link href="http://www.swr3.de/musik/poplexikon/-/id=927882/did=70326/i3zglz/index.html" itemprop="url">
                          <h5 itemprop="name">Genesis</h5>
```

This repeats a few times at the page (see the top link swr3.de) but I have no idea how to create a list with beautifulsoup & python like:

> Genesis - No son of mine
>   Double You - Please don't go

Comment: Do you have code? What have you tried?

Comment: Tryed it with this guide: http://youtu.be/M_4UIPLaIII but get only the artist name one time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/), and [lxml](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

First, install the **prerequisites:**

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install requests
pip install lxml
```

**swr3.py:**

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parsedsongs = []
result = requests.get('http://www.swr3.de//-/id=47424/cf=42/did=65794/93avs/index.html?hour=5&date=2015-10-23')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")
detailbodys = soup.find_all('div', 'detail-body')
for detailbody in detailbodys:
    title = detailbody.h4.string.encode('utf-8').strip()
    if detailbody.h5:
        artist = detailbody.h5.string.encode('utf-8').strip()
    else:
        artist = detailbody.span.string.encode('utf-8').strip()
    parsedsongs.append({'artist': artist, 'title': title})

for entry in parsedsongs:
    print 'Artist: {}\tTitle: {}'.format(entry['artist'], entry['title'])
```

The **output:**

```
(swr3)macbook:swr3 joeyoung$ python swr3.py
Artist: Vaya Con Dios   Title: Nah neh nah
Artist: Genesis Title: No son of mine
Artist: Genesis Title: No son of mine
Artist: Double You  Title: Please don't go
Artist: Stereo MC's Title: Step it up
Artist: Cranberries Title: Zombie
Artist: La Bouche   Title: Sweet dreams
Artist: Die Prinzen Title: Du mußt ein Schwein sein
Artist: Bad Religion    Title: Punk rock song
Artist: Bellini Title: Samba de Janeiro
Artist: Dion, Celine; Bee Gees  Title: Immortality
Artist: Jones, Tom; Mousse T.   Title: Sex bomb
Artist: Yanai, Kate Title: Bacardi feeling (Summer dreamin')
Artist: Heroes Del Silencio Title: Entre dos tierras
```